# Re-answer with the same answer that already deleted by a moderator

Tags: discussion

When I was beginner I made some mistakes, so a moderator removed my answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165076/create-backup-of-postgresql-via-processbuilder/37276465#37276465) (you can see the content only if you have the privilege for that). Can I re-answer this question with the same answer, or this is this forbidden?

Comment: I'm not sure why the moderators deleted it, are you?

Comment: yes @Robert Longson, because it was an answer for a friend, so he accept my answer and gives me the bounty, whatever the moderator suspect that we work together so he delete the answer, i don't mind about his decision, i just want to re-answer maybe someone can get the same problem

Comment: Flagging a moderator with a custom flag for undeletion, in which you explain why the answer now merits undeletion, is much better than writing a new answer. Although if the answer was deleted for a reason such as sockpuppetry or vote fraud you're unlikely to get far. In any case writing a new identical answer is not the way to go.

Comment: i already flag it i hope they can help me @RobertLongson

Comment: Don't say I didn't warn you that might not work given the fraud aspect. You can cancel the flag if you change your mind before a moderator sees it.

Answer (score 5):

If the moderator undeleted your question you'd get the bounty back which as it was awarded fraudulently is not going to happen.

If the moderator cancelled the bounty and then undeleted the question your friend would get the bounty rep back which seems unmerited too.

I think your best course of action is to accept that you've burned yourself on this question/answer and move on. Try to avoid answering questions that your friend has asked as you've already had problems with that and you don't want to get in trouble with the moderators again do you?

Comment: ok, i will wait the answer of a moderator then, thank you any way @Robert Longson

Comment: This about sums it up... I'd just ask @YCF_L why you're asking this 10 months later?

Comment: i need this solution again, so i searched for it, so i thought it can help others in future @JonClements

Comment: @YCF_L that's thoughtful of you. I think it's best to leave it though.

Comment: ok, what the solution then, avoid this idea because it is forbidden and make trouble with moderators or i can re-answer about this question?, i don't know what is the law in this case, you are a moderator @JonClements can you advice me with a solution?

Comment: @YCF_L I'd advise against re-answering - the question's lasted 10 months without it and since you have a certain amount of involvement with it one way or another etc... it's best left alone.

Comment: waaaaahhh, thank you @JonClements i will wait to hear something from another one i hope Tim Post can give me an answer or Brad Larson because he is the one who delete my answer

Comment: I wouldn't expect any other answer. The moderators all form a [gestalt mind](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Gestalt_Mind), it's part of their training isn't it @JonClements. Note this is a secret so Jon may deny it. :-)

Comment: @Robert how could I deny something that doesn't exist? :p

Comment: @YCF_L - Moderators cannot refund bounties once they are awarded, so I can't remove the bounty from this answer. As the bounty was obtained inappropriately, I won't undelete the answer. I'll disagree with Jon and recommend that you re-post the answer if you feel that strongly about it existing. In general, I delete any answers that obtained bounties via questionable means and don't undelete them because that would restore the bounty.